# How to set ImageView in CardView properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview

So I'm making a gallery like app and it needs some ScrollView and CardView inside it.

[This is the screenshot when I put some background in the ImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKkpI.jpg)

[This is how it suppose to look, I have removed the background image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XtlA.jpg)

I have tried to put an ImageView to inside the CardView with a Linear Layout but the Image filled the ScrollView Instead.

```
fun CreateCardView(ItemCount: Int){                                                         
   for (i in 1 until ItemCount){                                                           

       val card_view = CardView(this)                                                      
       val param = GridLayout.LayoutParams()                                               
       param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)                           
       param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)                        
       card_view.layoutParams = param                                                      
       val param2 = card_view.layoutParams as GridLayout.LayoutParams                                                                            
       card_view.layoutParams = param2                                                     
       subLayoutGrid?.addView(card_view)                                                                      

       val linearLayout = LinearLayout(this)                                               
       val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(                                      
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // CardView width                      
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT // CardView height                      
       )                                                                                                                                       
       linearLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams                                                                               
       linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#135517"))                        
       card_view.addView(linearLayout)                                                     


       val imageView = ImageView(this)                                                     
       val imageParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(                                       
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                                        
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT                                         
       )                                                                                   
       imageView.layoutParams = imageParams                                                                                                       
       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animaleight)                             
       val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(finallinearId)                              
       layout.addView(imageView)                                                           


   }                                                                                       

}
```

How can i achieve something like on the image 2 using ImageView

Comment: see the demo example of GridView to solved your problem. Please try it.

Comment: your question is unclear. What you are not able to achieve from the desired result with your current code ?

Comment: I have followed this already but the ImageView still fill the whole ScrollView. Any idea?

Comment: The ImageView is filling the whole scrollView instead of filling the CardView and respecting the CardView's height and width

Comment: i think instead of match parent use wrap content and add image with fixed sized like 40*40

Comment: Going to try it, I'll hit you back later

Comment: It just zoomed the Image in the ImageView

Comment: @GeraldTDPI Share your layout files

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it happens because u set width and height of your cardView as WRAP_CONTENT, and images that u put here is very big, so you should either change the size of images or use fixed size of cardView like 100dp height and 100dp-width, but that is not the best option or you can try to change your xml file, if you will put your xml file I will help you with that.
Also as long as it is LinearLayout try just put to every item "weight" parametr "1"

Comment: Yes i used a 520X520 Picture but i have tried to put it inside a same size imageview but its all fine :(

Comment: Ok then it will be very nice from you to put here xml if you want get help :)

Comment: Thankyou but I need to do it programatically because a card view represents an item and i have different categories for each items.

Comment: Got you, so did you try to put "weight" parametr to cardView?

Comment: Yes I did it this way

Comment: val param = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
                               
param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)     
       
param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)    
     
card_view.layoutParams = param

Comment: kk, then I dont know how to help you, sorry)

Comment: Its okay pal :)